# i'm dealing with cookies and session problems

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP and I just see the cookies and session notion. from my understanding when we log in, a session start, and a cookie with the ID of the session is stored in our computer. so my questions:
1-If we disconnect from the page. the cookie is destroyed or still remaining.
2-If it still remaining we can't have another account on the site because if we enter the page the session will continue because we have the cookie pre-existed so how can we have other accounts. I'm sorry for the bad English and thanks for your answers.

Comment: Yes, you keep the cookie. Sessions are stored on server side and their lifetime depend on server configuration. Usually, your /logout destroy the session so you can log on another account.

Answer (score 0):

1. The cookie exists until it expires
   [See the expires parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

2. Until the cookie expires, you are logged in to account 1. You must log out to log into another account.